# Draw an open Polygon in Java

Tags: java, 2d, polygon, graphic

I'm trying to draw an open rectangle using a Polygon:

```
int[] xPoints = {1,1,3,3};
int[] xPoints = {0,5,5,0};
polygone = new Polygon(xPoints, yPoints, 4);
g2d.draw(polygone);
```

Is there any way to have an open Polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at `java.awt.geom.Path2D`, used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9559831/230513), or `java.awt.geom.GeneralPath`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697773/230513).

Comment: I tried GeneralPath and It worked well. I have more control. Thanks