# Merging two polygons in Java

Tags: java, polygons

Is there a clean Java method for merging the points of two given overlapping polygons into one polygon?

Comment: Merging how? And what did you try?

Comment: how does your data structure look like?

Comment: Merging the points, and I tried to run through the points individually, and check for intersects. But it was an extremely intensive task to run on a polygon with over 1000 points.

Comment: still not clear what the problem is. please give an example

Comment: @BenPoulson - I still did not understand. e.g. If you had two squares side by side, with some space in between, how would you merge them? If instead, they shared an edge, how would you merge them then?

Comment: @ArjunShankar - I mentioned that the polygons where overlapping.

Comment: This [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9526835/230513) examines merging  a number of triangles; I don't know how it scales.

Comment: It's not clear what "clean" means in this context.

Comment: @BenPoulson - In that case, what do you mean by 'overlap'? Shared edges? Or shared area? My point is: The question is not clear enough. Please do consider an edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is a [Convex Hull Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) it will take a set of points and return a minimal set of points that encloses the original points. This can be done in `n.log n` time.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the convex hull algorithm is the correct way to be doing this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) (Java Topology Suite) for that.

- Create your Polygon objects
- Use the **union** method which will return a Set of all points from both polygons

Simple code example:

- Given Polygon 1 (as WKT): POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))
- Given Polygon 2 (as WKT): POLYGON ((5 5, 15 5, 15 15, 5 15, 5 5))

  ```
  // create polygons
  Polygon p1 = new GeometryFactory().createPolygon(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(0, 0), new Coordinate(0,10), new Coordinate(10,10), new Coordinate(10,0), new Coordinate(0,0)});
  Polygon p2 = new GeometryFactory().createPolygon(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(5,5), new Coordinate(15,5), new Coordinate(15,15), new Coordinate(5,15), new Coordinate(5,5)});
  // calculate union
  Geometry union = p1.union(p2);
  // print as WKT
  System.out.println(union.toText());
  ```

The result is a new polygon:

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 5 10, 5 15, 15 15, 15 5, 10 5, 10 0, 0 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Unfortunately while using this method to combine polygons, if you have polygons placed in a circular manner, the JTS really does not like that and won't overlay/union them properly. I'm not sure if I'm just doing something wrong, though.

Answer (score 6):

The [Area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class supports addition of closed polygons.

Comment: Upvoting this. Combining polygons means you have to be edge-aware, and convex hull algorithms typically just look at points. If you look at the [Area.add() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#add(java.awt.geom.Area)), a convex hull algorithm would just produce a rectangle.

Answer (score 6):

Convex Hull is different from adding. Adding means making a polygon that looks like the two polygons overlapped which is not necessarily convex.

Answer (score 1):

Using the algorithm @Charles Keepax provided, you can do something like this:

```
public static Polygon mergePolygons(Polygon a, Polygon b) {
    // create arrays for border of each polygon
    Point[] a_pts = new Point[a.npoints];
    Point[] b_pts = new Point[b.npoints];
    // fill them in an array of Points instead of separate coords.
    Arrays.setAll(a_pts, i -> new Point(a.xpoints[i], a.ypoints[i]));
    Arrays.setAll(b_pts, i -> new Point(b.xpoints[i], b.ypoints[i]));
    // first merge 2 arrays into 1
    Point[] all_pts = (Point[]) mergeArrays(a_pts, b_pts);
    // apply Convex Hull on resulting array
    convexHull(all_pts, all_pts.length);

    // separate x and y coordinates back 
    int[] x_pts = new int[all_pts.length];
    int[] y_pts = new int[all_pts.length];
    Arrays.setAll(x_pts, i -> all_pts[i].x);
    Arrays.setAll(y_pts, i -> all_pts[i].y);
    // return polygon object using those coordinates
    return new Polygon(x_pts, y_pts, all_pts.length);
}
```

But of course solution by @Lars is more practical, this is how you could do it in a naive way.